# How to specify GPIO port for dht11 driver?

Tags: linux, drivers, kernel-modules

I'm working with dht11 sensor on my raspberry pi 3.

I found dht11 driver's source code in linux

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/iio/humidity/dht11.c

And I successfully compiled the module and executed `insmod` on my board.

But I don't know how to specify the GPIO port number for the driver.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/iio/humidity/dht11.txt) ...

Comment: see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236530/dht21-am2301-sensor-not-measuring-humidity

Comment: I have read much material about device tree, but still don't know how to compile the dtbo files and how to update them for my board. Can you give me some help?

Comment: There is a program called `dtc` (device tree compiler? - but not sure it is a compiler?) which will convert between `dts` and `dtb` - you should find it in your kernel source. The device tree source is also in there. Some embedded platforms have their own device tree source, so be careful.